# What does C "Sleep" function (capital "S") do on a Mac?

Tags: xcode, macos, sleep

Note the capital "S" in `Sleep`.  `Sleep` with a capital "S" is a standard function that sleeps milliseconds on the PC.  On Mac OS X, there is no such symbol.  However, the Xcode linking environment seems to find something to link it to.  What is it?

Comment: Google was broken?  The Objective C SDK Help was broken?  You have no resources at all?

Comment: @S. Lott: AFAIK there is no way to make a Google search case-sensitive, so how do you search for Sleep but not sleep?

Comment: I'd guess that it might be a legacy API, but I don't have enough disk space to download the legacy doc set.

Comment: Holy crap, that made my MacBook go to sleep…

Comment: "`Sleep()` on a PC" (by which I assume you mean Win32) is not "standard".  Win32 is not standardized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it’s an old old Carbon function (in the CoreServices / OSServices framework) that puts the computer to sleep. I can’t find any documentation.

- [Sleep and Xcode](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/247054-sleep-and-xcode.html)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the correct answer, because that is the odd behavior I am seeing.  Other bad things ensue, but the machine powers off it's monitor and disk.

Answer (score 2):

sleep(int) is a method from the unix system that run mac Known as Darwin.

[Here is the ManPage for sleep](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sleep.3.html)

Essentially it is a C call that lets you tell the computer to sleep for 'int' number of seconds.

alternatively you can use 'usleep(unsigned int)' which will sleep for 'unsigned int' number of "microseconds" which is second * 1000 * 1000 or 1000 milliseconds.

[Here is the ManPage for usleep](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/usleep.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/usleep)

Both of these functions are wrapped to allow you access to the underlying "C/C++" methods that a normal C/C++ developer would use.

here is an equivalent code example

```
NSTimeInterval sleepTime = 2.0; //Time interval is a double containing fractions of seconds
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:sleepTime]; // This will sleep for 2 seconds
sleep((int)sleepTime); // This will also sleep for 2 seconds
```

if you wish to have more granularity you will need usleep(unsigned int) which will give you a much more precise number.

```
NSTimeInterval sleepTime = 0.2; // This is essentially 2 tenths of a second
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:sleepTime]; // This will sleep for 2 tenths of a second;
usleep((unsigned int)(sleepTime * 1000 * 1000)); // This will also sleep for 2 tenths of a second
```

I hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent to sleep should be

[`NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0];`

However this is in seconds. To use milliseconds I think you have to use usleep( num * 1000), where num is number of mills

But I don't know what Sleep(...) does

Comment: yes, I know how to sleep properly on the mac too.  My question is, what is my cross-platform braino doing ?

Answer (score 0):

> On the mac, under OSX, there is no such symbol.

I don't think there is such a symbol in Classic mac either - I even looked in my ancient copy of [THINK Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/THINK_Reference).

I would also be surprised to find a `Sleep` (with a capital S) function in C, since many people name C functions using all lower case.

Were you prompted to ask the question because you're getting a link error?

Comment: I think he's asking the question because he's (unexpectedly) _not_ getting a link error.

Comment: I get a link error on a handy project that's just linking with the Carbon framework. It must be defined in something else.

Answer (score 0):

There is usleep().

```
pthread_create(&pth,NULL,threadFunc,"foo");

while(i < 100)
{
    usleep(1);
    printf("main is running...\n");
    ++i;
}

printf("main waiting for thread to terminate...\n");
pthread_join(pth,NULL);

return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any other libraries in your project?

I'm getting compile errors using both Cocoa and Carbon using apple's template projects, however I notice that sleep functions (using the definition) are a feature in both the SDL and SFML cross platform libraries, and perhaps for many others.

Have you tried your code example on a template project using only with apples libraries?

It could be that `Sleep()` is a function in something else you are linking to.