# Programmatically put a Mac into sleep

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, sleep

I can't find any instructions how to put a Mac programmatically into sleep mode (in Objective-C). I'm sure it should be only one line, but could you give me a hint?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315685/how-to-wake-from-sleep-programmatically

Comment: Yea it's kind of related, but not answering my question anyhow.

Comment: But it might be interesting for others who visit this question.

Comment: You [can call `Sleep`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827158/what-does-a-c-function-named-sleep-do-on-a-mac), but I hope there’s actually a proper Cocoa function.

Comment: jleedev, you misunderstood my question. I asked for putting the Mac into sleep mode ;-)

Comment: @septi: Actually, no, he did not misunderstand the question. `Sleep` is an old function that puts the machine to sleep. Nowadays, it's not even declared in the headers, but it does still exist even in 64-bit and commenters on the question @jleedev linked to reported that it still works.

Comment: (Remember that C, and, by extension, Objective-C, is case-sensitive. `Sleep` is not the same as `sleep`; they are not the same function, and, as anyone who calls the wrong one will find out, they do not do the same thing.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>

SendAppleEventToSystemProcess(kAESleep);

OSStatus SendAppleEventToSystemProcess(AEEventID EventToSend)
{
    AEAddressDesc targetDesc;
    static const ProcessSerialNumber kPSNOfSystemProcess = { 0, kSystemProcess };
    AppleEvent eventReply = {typeNull, NULL};
    AppleEvent appleEventToSend = {typeNull, NULL};

    OSStatus error = noErr;

    error = AECreateDesc(typeProcessSerialNumber, &kPSNOfSystemProcess, 
                                            sizeof(kPSNOfSystemProcess), &targetDesc);

    if (error != noErr)
    {
        return(error);
    }

    error = AECreateAppleEvent(kCoreEventClass, EventToSend, &targetDesc, 
                   kAutoGenerateReturnID, kAnyTransactionID, &appleEventToSend);

    AEDisposeDesc(&targetDesc);
    if (error != noErr)
    {
        return(error);
    }

    error = AESend(&appleEventToSend, &eventReply, kAENoReply, 
                  kAENormalPriority, kAEDefaultTimeout, NULL, NULL);

    AEDisposeDesc(&appleEventToSend);
    if (error != noErr)
    {
        return(error);
    }

    AEDisposeDesc(&eventReply);

    return(error); 
}
```

More detail on https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1134/_index.html

Comment: Here's a version that doesn't require importing anything and works on 64-bit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6283690/35690

Answer (score 8):

You can also use scripting bridge. Draft code is

```
SystemEventsApplication *systemEvents = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.systemevents"];
[systemEvents sleep];
```

Comment: This one works in a sandboxed app on Mountain Lion, too. Thanks! :)

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but this one doesn't work in a sandboxed app anymore. Didn't find another way either.

Answer (score 7):

Tom is correct. The AE methods fail if the display is sleeping. pmset sleepnow works 100%.

```
NSTask  *pmsetTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];
pmsetTask.launchPath = @"/usr/bin/pmset";
pmsetTask.arguments = @[@"sleepnow"];
[pmsetTask launch];
```

Comment: This one works on 10.13 sandboxed the others not anymore!

Answer (score 6):

You can use AppleScript

```
NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"tell application \"System Events\" to sleep"];
NSDictionary *errorInfo;
[script executeAndReturnError:&errorInfo];
[script release];
```

Comment: I know it works with AppleScript, but I would like to do it with Obj-C. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone is curious how `pmset sleepnow` actually works - it uses [IOPMSleepSystem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/1557121-iopmsleepsystem?language=objc) API from the Power Management section of the IOKit framework. You can check this via examining the [pmset.c source code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/PowerManagement/PowerManagement-703.30.3/pmset/pmset.c.auto.html) (link from macOS 10.13.3).

So instead of calling `pmset` you can request sleep via the following snippet:

```
#include <IOKit/pwr_mgt/IOPMLib.h>

void SleepNow()
{
    io_connect_t fb = IOPMFindPowerManagement(MACH_PORT_NULL);
    if (fb != MACH_PORT_NULL)
    {
        IOPMSleepSystem(fb);
        IOServiceClose(fb);
    }
}
```

Don't be scared by the *caller must be root or **the console user*** remark in the documentation since it appears to be working for any standard logged in user.

By following the source code, it looks like it calls into `IOUserClient::clientHasPrivilege` with `kIOClientPrivilegeLocalUser` which ends up checking if the caller is present in the `IOConsoleUsers` array in the root IORegistry entry, and apparently currently logged in user is always present there.

Answer (score 1):

I found that running `pmset sleepnow` worked during a screensaver, while the first two answers did not.