# Couldn't import SystemEventsApplication

Tags: cocoa

Try use this part part code

```
-(IBAction)goAway:(id)sender{
    SystemEventsApplication *systemEvents = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.systemevents"];
    [systemEvents sleep];
}
```

But couldn't find from where import SystemEventsApplication and couldn't import SystemEvents.h

Find this solution here [Programmatically put a Mac into sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243140/programmatically-put-a-mac-into-sleep)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use Scripting Bridge you need to generate header files from the scripting definitions of the application in question. The [Preparing to Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/UsingScriptingBridge/UsingScriptingBridge.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006104-CH4-DontLinkElementID_12) section of the Scripting Bridge Programming Guide leads with the following:

> Before you begin writing any Scripting Bridge code for your project, there are a few steps you should complete:
>
> 1. Generate header files for all scriptable applications that your code is sending messages to.
> 2. Add these files to your project.
> 3. In your header or implementation files, add #import statements for the generated header files.
> 4. Add the Scripting Bridge framework to your project.

It goes on to say:

> To create a header file, you need to run two command-line tools—sdef and sdp—together, with the output from one piped to the other. This is the recommended syntax:
>
> sdef */path/to/application.app* | sdp -fh --basename *applicationName*

So, for scripting using System Events you'd run:

```
sdef /System/Library/CoreServices/System\ Events.app | sdp -fh --basename SystemEvents
```

This would generate `SystemEvents.h`, containing a definition for `SystemEventsApplication`, which you can then include in your project.